# Activity to get Version Control Path

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

How can I get the Version Control Path that has been selected in the Edit Build Definition window?

I need this value to get a file using the DownloadFile task.

[image: Edit Build Definition window]

I need to get the settings from this Source Settings tab, specifically the Source Control Folder column.

PS: My template is based on UpgradeTemplate.xaml

Comment: which version control path?  You mean the Projects To Build, or the workspace mappings?

Comment: @DylanSmith the path to the projects to build.  Example: $\directory\project

Comment: @DylanSmith I've added a screenshot to illustrate what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working using the following statement:

```
BuildDetail.BuildDefinition.Workspace.Mappings(0).ServerItem
```